# How to instatiate dialogfragment in a project

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am done with a flag quiz app, it turns  out however, that the  app doesn't run smoothly. I have  debugged several times. Presently, I am stuck. Initially the exception was  fragment null must be public static in order to recreate Instance..or something like that. After several, several hours of surfing the net for solutions I created a new class, there is no error in this class  but it is coloured red. Why is this?, also what do I need  to use the complete or correct  this code. eg Studio is  saying void showDialog() is not used below is a portion of my MainActivity Fragment

```
               guessButton = ((Button) v);
                String guess = guessButton.getText().toString();
                String answer = getCountryName(correctAnswer);
                ++totalGuesses;

                if (guess.equals(answer)) {
                    ++correctAnswers;


                    answerTextView.setText(answer + "!");
                    answerTextView.setTextColor(
                            getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_answer));

                    disableButtons();
                    if (correctAnswers == FLAGS_IN_QUIZ) {
                        resetQuiz();

                        void showDialog(){
                            DialogFragment newFragment = MyNewFragment.newInstance();
                            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "QUIZ RESULTS");
                            newFragment.setCancelable(false);
                        }
                        public void doPositiveClick(){
                        Log.i(" fragmentdialog" , "positive click");








                    }
                }

                else {

                        handler.postDelayed(
                                new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        animate(true);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);

                    }
                } else {
                    flagImageView.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);

                    answerTextView.setText((R.string.incorrect_answer));
                    answerTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),
                            R.color.incorrect_answer));
                    guessButton.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }

            ;


            private void disableButtons() {
                for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++) {

                    LinearLayout guessRow = guessLinearLayouts[row];
                    for (int i = 0; i < guessRow.getChildCount(); i++)
                        guessRow.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
        };
        }
```

Below is the   new class that keeps  on appearing red.

```
             public class MyNewFragment extends DialogFragment {
public static MyNewFragment newInstance() {
   MyNewFragment frag = new MyNewFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())

            .setMessage("fff")

            .setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {




                        }
                    }
            );
    return builder.create();

   }
  };
```

I will appreciate a precise answer that helps solve these problems

Comment: i can't find out the problem, ask your question clear

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are somehow declaring methods within if-then-else clauses, hence Android Studio is saying the are unused.  The snippet of code where you attempt to launch the DialogFragment should look more like this (i.e. without the surrounding `void showDialog() {}` method definition):

```
  if (correctAnswers == FLAGS_IN_QUIZ) {
           resetQuiz();
           DialogFragment newFragment = MyNewFragment.newInstance();
           newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "QUIZ RESULTS");
           newFragment.setCancelable(false);
  }
```

I can't see anything significantly wrong with your definition of MyNewFragment, although you have an empty OnClickListener.OnClick() definition and you are setting the fragment arguments to an empty Bundle. However neither of these issues would generate a Studio compiler error making it show red. Find where Studio is indicating the errors and it will tell you what's wrong with your code.